# How do I align these links inside inline-blocks to the top?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a little CSS problem with a list of thumbnails. Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/22hs8/

The problem is that when the link is too long to fit in the 150px block it will push the image down. By using `inline-block` on the list elements instead of a float I could get the images to line up properly, but now I want to have the links at the same height as well.

One thing I tried is making the links itself a block (or surrounding it by a div) and giving that a height, but that would mean they are always the same height even if none of the links uses two rules. Also, if a link is so long it uses three lines the same problem would occur.

In short: how do I align the links to the top of the list items, without breaking the image alignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address one issue, you can add `vertical-align:top;` to the `<li>` tag in order to align the content to the top of the element, but unfortunately, I don't believe there's a way to resolve the issue entirely without also implementing one of the following methods:

1. Placing all of the  tags in a separate
2. Specifying a height on the  tags
3. Using javascript to equalize heights

---

### Options

#### 1. Separate Div

By moving the anchor tags into a separate div, they could be given the same width as the images and floated or displayed inline accordingly, but your markup becomes less semantic when you separate the anchor from the content (and may also be programmatically more complex if these are being dynamically generated).

#### 2. Specifying a Height

This option can be thrown out almost immediately because, as you've stated, the anchor lengths can fluctuate to multiple lines. You could specify the height the the largest know line length, but then you'll ultimately end up with unnecessary white space with groups of short links.

#### 3. JavaScript (jQuery)

While It would be ideal to resolve this issue without the requirement of JavaScript, I think it may be the only option that would allow you to preserve the semantics of your markup, and also apply an equal height to each of the anchor tags.

---

### Recommended Solution

I would recommend setting a default height on the anchors of the largest known line length, then applying a bit of jQuery to normalize the heights of the anchors. This way, if the JavaScript parsing fails or JavaScript is disabled, the user still sees a uniform layout (albeit with potentially more whitespace), and with JavaScript active the heights are normalized.

- Apply `vertical-align:top;` to the `<li>`
- Define default height for non-js users
- Equalize heights using jQuery:

  ```
  (function(){
      $.fn.equalizeHeights = function(){
          return this.height( Math.max.apply(this, $(this).map(function(i,e){ return $(e).height() }).get() ))
      }
      $(function(){ $('li a').equalizeHeights(); });
  })();
  ```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Eg7hy/

Comment: Good answer. Unfortunately the first solution is not really semantically correct, but I do feel it is one of the cleanest solutions code-wise. I might just do that. 
The fixed height problem I already dismissed in my question. I thought about the JavaScript solution as well, but I don't feel comfortable having to resort to that for such a minor layout issue.  Thanks for the in-depth answer though. I will discuss this with the guy responsible for the requirements and see which of the answers would fit our website best :)

Comment: Requirements have changed, which allowed me to solve it in a slightly different way. This answer was still the best imo.

Answer (score 2):

How is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/22hs8/3/

Comment: If the title ends up being three lines or longer, it runs over the image.

Comment: Is the title height totally dynamic?

Comment: This is one of the solutions I mentioned in my question. The problem is that it's not dynamic enough. If I can be sure links would never exceed two rules I might just use this after all, but at the moment I can't.

Answer (score 1):

So you're saying that you want the links to not push the content down? I don't see that as being possible unless you don't allow your content to stretch at all. It's natural flow of a page for something above content to force the content down after it if it needs more space.

Have you thought about chopping off the text after a certain number of characters, with a '...' and providing the full text through a `title`, and providing the full text through a popup (since I assume you're creating some kind of photo gallery)?

Comment: I thought of that, but I'm not sure if the requirements allow it. I got pretty far using text-overflow: ellipsis (just needs a little extra firefox hack), but these decisions are not up to me (just an HTML codemonkey :P). Might be a good solution though.

Comment: Coding for an employer I take it? It's always good to show them what could possibly happen if they don't take your suggestion and provide examples of other websites that use what you're talking to them about. You can also use PHP to cut off the text after a certain point and tack on the ellipsis. I'm pretty sure other programming languages do this as well.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer that came to mind was:

"just use a table, it makes this *really easy*, and works everywhere"

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/paWn6/)

---

However, I would probably get down voted into oblivion if I posted an answer only containing a `<table>` tag version, so here's a version using CSS `display: table` and friends:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/eL5tT/)

Of course, that won't work in IE7 because that browser [doesn't support `display: table`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html).

I can't think of a way to do this using code closer to your original and `display: inline-block`, which would also support an arbitrary number of lines. I'd love to see a better way to do this.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell"><a href="#">Some text</a></div>
        <div class="cell"><a href="#">Some more text (too long)</a></div>
        <div class="cell"><a href="#">Some text</a></div>
        <div class="cell"><a href="#">Some text (seriously too long) text text text text text text text text text text text text text</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell"><div class="image">image</div></div>
        <div class="cell"><div class="image">image</div></div>
        <div class="cell"><div class="image">image</div></div>
        <div class="cell"><div class="image">image</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*(you could change some of those `div` tags into `ul` and `li` if you wanted to)*

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    display: table
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
    text-align: center
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 150px
}
.image {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: grey
}
```

Comment: Ugh, why would I go through all that trouble if I could just use a table... Oh yeah, because it's completely unsemantic HTML. Using nested divs to simulate a table is like the worst solution ever.

Comment: @Stephan Muller: Example: http://jsfiddle.net/eL5tT/2/ - Certainly nicer than using Javascript unless it's exceptionally important to you that the link and image be in the same element (I can't see why it would be). If IE7 support is vital to you, you could perhaps serve Javascript to fix it through an IE conditional comment.

Comment: @Myles Gray: Appreciated. It did irritate me at the time that I got a downvote for what I thought was a useful idea.

Comment: I have used your above technique to other questions's answers and not received down-vote, you just can't please some people... I felt it was an injustice for a good solution as well as the time and effort put into this.

Answer (score -1):

Add `vertical-align:top;` to the images.

Comment: You can add vertical-align to images to align the text near them.

Comment: For example, look at this and try to remove the vertical-align: http://jsfiddle.net/M4vRE/